# Instant app Internal test behavior

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I uploaded an instant app on internal test track and created a tester list with 3 testers. I send the opt-in URL to all testers and they accepted the inviation to be a tester.

I uploaded assetlinks.json to my website (www.example.com) and added applinks to my instant app.

1. Will the testers be able to see TRY NOW in play store for my instant app ?
2. Can they access instant app through the URL www.example.com/test

Also this is quoted in android developer site

"To test your instant app's deployment on the internal testing track through Google Play, you must have a draft form of your app's installable version in the Google Play Console."

My application is already published on play store. Do I have to make aseperate draft again ?

Comment: Yes and yes. Although my experience was that it takes 2-3 days from opting in until they start getting the instant app.

Comment: Thanks Hassan, does it take that much time for every release or just first time ?

Comment: From what I noticed, it's mostly per device or Google account. The opting in is what takes time, not updates or app publishing.

Comment: Its over 3 days and my testers are not able to see the TRY NOW button nor he is able to access the instant app through URL I did not get any error while uploading or rolling out internal test release on play console. I emailed goggle support about this.

Comment: How do internal testers get instant app, do they automatically recieve it in their recent app list or they have to manually tap TRY NOW in play store to get Instant app on their device ?

Comment: They have to either press the try now button, or open any web link that you support in your manifest.

Comment: What are the debugging steps if Internal test users do not recieve Instant app ?

Comment: Do I need to have a installable version of app in internal test too ?

Answer (score 6):

This should work. After adding the testers, be sure that you send them the opt-in links and they accept. Once they have opted in, you may want to trigger a reload of their cached instant app list (this is the thing that takes a few days to sync on its own). There are a few ways to do this:

- While connected to WiFi, unplug the device and plug it back in
- Opt out and back in to instant apps (Settings > Google > Instant Apps)
- Run `adb shell am broadcast -a com.google.android.finsky.action.CONTENT_FILTERS_CHANGED` from a connected machine set up for USB debugging.

Comment: I uploaded a installable app version along with instant app on internal test track. Now it works, testers are able to see the instant app .

Answer (score 1):

Finally my testers are able to see instant app, I want to share the steps for uploading the instant app on internal test track,

- Make sure the targetting for instant app and installable app matches.
- Upload the installable app on internal test track.
- Upload the instant app on internal test track and resolve any error.
- Share the opt-in url with testers.
- Your testers should accept the invite.
- They will start seeing the TRY NOW button on play store after a while.

Comment: How much is "a while" Is it "hours"? days ?

Comment: for me, it was 7-8 hours but I have seen it coming at most by 2 days.